# Poll dynamodb stream nextShardIterator is never null resulting in an infinite loop

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am trying to consume a dynamodb stream and would like to understand the best way to consume it.

I run a periodic job every 2s that polls the stream. It then lifts all the new records from the stream and processes them. While I process these records I insert items into a new table and I use the transact write api to do this. Hence I am limited to 25 at a time (recently this is now a 100). To be safe I batch up 20 items at a time. To be clear, I consume all new records from the stream but I batch up 20 at a time and process them.

I also construct a cursor of the stream I am reading - this has the shard ids and the last processed sequence numbers in a map. I save this cursor along with the new items into the new table.

The next time the job polls the stream, it uses the cursor and then reads the next set of records to process.

This is what I am doing:

1. I make a call to describe the stream - this gives me all the shards. This AWS call is paginated as well, but I process just the first page of shards every time I run the job as I save the lastEvaluatedShardId into the cursor for next time.
2. Once I have the shards, I then compare it with the cursor I have saved. It either will be present with the last item processed in the map, or it might be a new one. I add it into the cursor and then loop through the entire set.
3. For every shard in the loop, I make a call to get the shard iterator. I pass in the last processed sequence number if known so that I iterate after that sequence number or I start from trim horizon.
4. Once I have the shard iterator, I then get records from the stream using the shard iterator. This is where I have a problem.

The get records call returns a nextShardIterator that is not null but no records in the response. I understand that the shard is still open and can receive more records and hence the nextShardIterator will not be null. But I can't keep looping indefinitely in the hope of a new record coming in. I would like to exit the loop iteration that is processing the current shard and move onto the next shard. If all the shards are done, the job ends and restarts 2s later.

When do I break from the get records loop? Also if I get the same shard again, I should probably start from the last place I iterated from. So do I save the nextShardIterator and keep going?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to re-invent the wheel? DynamoDB has a Kinesis Client Adapter that you can use with the Kinesis Client Library which handles all of the overheads you're talking about, such as listing shards and storing the last iterator position.

I strongly suggest you make use of this library to avoid any issue in production.

[image: KCL]

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.KCLAdapter.html

Comment: I need a guarantee that a record that has been processed is not processed again. Exactly once semantics. Is that possible with KCL? This is the reason why I was committing a cursor along with result of the processing the records from the stream in the same transaction.

Comment: DynamoDB streams provides exactly once event, but KCL may not. Idempotency is something you should apply in your consumer. They KCL is merely a delivery mechanism.